# Modify button form in Qt

Tags: qt

I'm new on Qt and I'm looking for some way to modify the form of a QPushButton, but I didn't find something on the web.
Is it possible and if so, how can I do this?
Thx

Comment: By form, do you mean the visual aspect ? the shape ?

Comment: It is still unclear what you want to achieve. Perhaps images of what you have now and what you want would help (someone with more reputation points can edit them to be shown in the question, if you provide links, use imgur or something).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to change how the QPushButton looks, you can use the [Qt style sheets](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/stylesheet.html). If you want to put an image on the button, you can take advantage of the "background-image" property of the QPushButton

```
QPushButton
{
    background-image: url("alpha.jpg");
}
```

You can change other properties like "border", "background-color", etc. Your question needs to be more specific as to what visual elements you need. Go through the documentation, it will help you.

One way to go about getting a different for the QPushButton is to make the necessary image available. Get the necessary image and make sure it has a transparent background. Use could use other attributes of QPushButton like, "background-color: transparent" and without any border - "border: none".

Hope it helps!

Comment: Ok, sorry... Currently, a QpushButton is a square and I want use an other shape to display the button.

Comment: you could use an image with transparent background, set the background color attribute to transparent